# AS3 & Facebook Connect : popup not showing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, facebook

I've got a strange bug when trying to use facebook connect with actionscript3.

I checked everything, couldn't find a way to resolve this.

Look at this :http://tinyurl.com/FBas3test-2

When clicking on "login", the facebook popup appears.

But within this swf (click on the "facebook" logo),
http://tinyurl.com/FBas3test-1
It does not work.
This is almost the same actionscript code; and it IS the same HTML.

You can check some debug informations with the firebug console.

Seems the javascript & HTML code is OK.
When clicking the Facebook logo, the HTML is updated.  Guess facebook IS contacted; but then no popup is shown.

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: PS : login:dracula / password:lugosi

Comment: PS2 : actionscript code here : http://pastie.org/2011560

Answer (score 0):

The popup is not showing for me at first because the popup blocker is blocking it.  In Chrome, I had to click the icon in the upper right to allow popups and then it worked.  I don't know exactly how ActionScript facebook sdk works, but if it is using Facebooks javascript sdk, try changing display mode from popup to dialog so that it shows in the same window.  Otherwise, you will need to figure out how to get actionscript to show a popup window without the browser popup blocker blocking it.